# bash JSON with jq - how to check for empty JSON members?

Tags: json, bash, if-statement, jq

I want to detect an error depending on an error message JSON field being empty or non-empty . I am using jq to slice out the member, but then have massive trouble evaluating it in my bash "if".

I have a json file referenced by my variable $input which does have an errMsg member, but as an empty string (note that my CLI prompt is ~$) :

```
~$ echo $(jq "." $input)
{ "projectCode": "145", "fullCode": "1", "errMsg": "" }
```

retrieving the errMsg field in this case properly yields an empty string:

```
~$ err=$(jq ".errMsg" $input)
~$ echo $err
""
```

Problem : testing that variable seems impossible :

```
~$ if [ $err = "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi 
CONTENT
```

I excpected the EMPTY as $err just showed "". Checking other way around:

```
~$ if [ $err != "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
EMPTY
```

so $err is apparently not "", even though echo $err yields "" ? 
How can that be ? What bash feature  am I missing here ?

Anyway, lets try that with a non-empty json (after changing the $input content):

```
~$ echo $(jq "." $input)
{ "projectCode": "145", "fullCode": "1", "errMsg": "not empty" }
~$ echo $err
"not empty"

~$ if [ $err != "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

okay, then masking like this :

```
~$ if [ "$err" != "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

I guess it finds a second token after "not" and doesnt like it. 
After much research i find this truly unreadable solution that seems to work:

```
~$ val=$(sed "s/^\(\"\)\(.*\)\1\$/\2/g" <<<"$err" | sed -e 's/\s.*$//')
~$ if [ "$val" = "" ]; then echo "NO ERROR"; else echo "ERROR"; fi
NO ERROR
```

it also works for non-empty errMsg members. Please, there MUST be a simple and elegant solution to this.

Comment: `[ $err = "" ]` isn't safe bash code; nothing to do with `jq`. If `err` is empty, then it runs `[ = "" ]`, which isn't valid syntax. You need `[ "$err" = "" ]`.

Comment: As for ```if [ "$err" != "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi``` -- it really, truly *is not* a syntax error (though the `!=` means there's a logic error). See it running correctly at https://ideone.com/CblHNK

Comment: ...if you could provide a [mcve] in the form of code other people could copy-and-paste to reproduce that particular bug (ideally, a reproducer tested to work on ideone or another unbiased 3rd-party sandbox), I'd be very interested to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over this from the top so you understand what's happening.

> ```
> ~$ err=$(jq ".errMsg" $input)
> ~$ echo $err
> ""
> ```

This output indicates that `err` contains `""` (it may also have some spaces before and after the `""`).
This is not the same thing as an empty string.
It's literally two double-quote characters.

> ```
> ~$ if [ $err = "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi 
> CONTENT
> ```
>
> I excpected the EMPTY as $err just showed "".

As mentioned earlier, `$err` is not empty, it contains two double-quotes.
On the other hand, in the Bash statement `[ ... = "" ]` the `""` does really mean an empty value.

The Bash statement `[ $err = "" ]` is problematic,
because it will result in a syntax error if the value of `$err` is empty,
or if it contains whitespace (assuming you haven't customized `IFS`).

The correct way to write this statement to enclose `$err` in double-quotes:

```
if [ "$err" = "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
```

The same goes for the `$input` variable in your first command, it should be written as:

```
err=$(jq ".errMsg" "$input")
```

---

If you want to check for empty `.errMsg` value in the object,
you have at least two options.

Option 1: check that the value is `""`.

```
if [ "$err" = '""' ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
```

Option 2: make `jq` output in raw mode, so it doesn't include the enclosing double-quotes around string values.

```
err=$(jq -r ".errMsg" "$input")
if [ "$err" = "" ]; then echo EMPTY; else echo CONTENT; fi
```

I recommend this latter option, so that the value of `err` will be the real value. The enclosing double-quotes seem just noise for your purpose.

Comment: thanks, that jq -r is just what was needed. Short, concise, works. No more sed needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your entire structure into a native bash associative array as follows:

```
declare -A data=( )
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key value; do
  data[$key]=$value
done < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv' "$input")
```

From there, you have several options: You can check items individually...

```
[[ ${data[errMsg]} ]] || echo "ERROR: errMsg is not set!"
```

...or you can loop over all of them:

```
for key in "${!data[@]}"; do
    [[ ${data[$key]} ]] || echo "ERROR: ${key} is not set!"
done
```